# Microsoft Graph API - Sending message in a channel error

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Get error response when calling the below API. I think I have all the permissions needed for this API. Any idea what I am missing here? Thanks!

Request:
POST /teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/messages
Authorization: Bearer <access_token>

Response:
401
{
"error": {
"code": "Unauthorized",
"message": "Message POST is allowed in application-only context only for import purposes. Refer to https://docs.microsoft.com/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/import-messages/import-external-messages-to-teams for more details."
}
}

Checking all the required permissions needed for this API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error usually occurs if you are using **client credentials** flow to generate bearer token where `Application` permissions only work with API calls.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I registered one Azure AD application and added all required **API permissions** like below:

[image]

Now, I generated one bearer token using **client credentials** flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: <appID>
client_secret: <secret> 
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to send message by calling below query, I got **same error** like this:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/messages
{
  "body": {
    "content": "Hello World"
  }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

> To resolve the error, you need to use **Delegated** flows like Authorization code flow to generate bearer token.

You can make use of below **authorization request** to get `code` value:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?client_id=<appID>
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope= https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

When I ran above request in browser, I got `code` value in address bar after signing in successfully like below:

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** using authorization code flow via Postman with below parameters like this:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id: <appID>
client_secret: <secret>
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
code: <paste_code_from_above_request>
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to send message in channel by calling below query, I got **response** successfully like below:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/messages
{
  "body": {
    "content": "Hello World"
  }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]